# Shortening repetitive codes

Tags: python, discord

I want to shorten these codes. The x part is a different message and the y part is the token of a different account. It has to be different each time. For example, after doing it, it goes to the next account and writes the next message.

```
import requests



payloud = {
    'content': "x"
}

header = {
    'authorization': 'y'
}

r = requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/1007038944707346502/messages", data=payloud, headers=header)
```

i tried creating a text document and using the contents but i couldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list of dicts:

```
import requests


url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/1007038944707346502/messages"
lst = [{'payloud' : {'content': "x"},'header' : {'authorization': 'y'}}, {'payloud' : {'content': "z"},'header' : {'authorization': 'xy'}}...]
for i in lst:
    r = requests.post(url, data=i['payloud'], headers=i['header'])
```

Comment: thx mate .Do you know how I can patch the content part and the authorization part by writing it in a text document?